# How do I write get element by id using if statement so that when one button is clicked it shows the div and hides the rest?

Tags: jquery, html

So on click of one of these buttons I want to hide the rest and just show the div belonging to the button that is clicked. I.e if I click allButton everything shows. If i click onButton, only the online Div shows, vice versa for offButton.

My online div is under class 'onlineWrapper' and my offline div is under class 'offlineWrapper'.

I want to write an if statement combined with get element by id (if that is a good way) to do this, instead of individually writing .hide() or .toggle() for each button.

What is the best way I can do this on jquery?

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class='allButton'>All</button>
  <button class='onButton'>Online</button>
  <button class='offButton'>Offline</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need any comparison to do what you described... Just an event handler for each button. See below:

```js
$(".onButton").on("click",function(){
  $("#onlineWrapper").show();
  $("#offlineWrapper").hide();
});
$(".offButton").on("click",function(){
  $("#onlineWrapper").hide();
  $("#offlineWrapper").show();
});
$(".allButton").on("click",function(){
  $("#onlineWrapper").show();
  $("#offlineWrapper").show();
});
```

```css
#onlineWrapper, #offlineWrapper{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button class='allButton'>All</button>
  <button class='onButton'>Online</button>
  <button class='offButton'>Offline</button>
</div>

<div id="onlineWrapper">Online div</div>
<div id="offlineWrapper">Offline div</div>
```

Comment: I get this part, but for learning purposes i was wondering how to accomplish this using an if statement?

Comment: The `if` statement is used to perform a comparison and obtain a boolean result. So the question is: What do you want to compare? I don't see a use here.